# Unable to kill a worker thread in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, multithreading

I'm working on a multi-threaded Silverlight application.

The application has two threads: Main/UI and a background working thread.

The UI thread should be able to kill the background thread, like so:

```
private Thread executionThread;

....

executionThread = new Thread(ExecuteStart);
executionThread.Start();

....

executionThread.Abort(); // when the user clicks "Stop"
```

The last line raises an Exception:

> MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed: System.Threading.Thread.Abort()

Any idea? why i cannot abort a thread in Silverlight?

Thanks,
Naimi

Comment: This might also be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc765416.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than creating a Thread manually for this purpose you might want to consider using the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(VS.95).aspx) class.

This class has built in functionality for cancelling the asynchronous operation when WorkerSupportsCancellation = true.

Have a look at this article on MSDN for a [full example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(VS.95).aspx) of how to use the BackgroundWorker in Silverlight.

Comment: The BackgroundWroker requires the worker thread to constantly check for cancellation. Is there a way to immediately force the worker thread to exist?

Comment: I'd advise you not to pursue the notion of "forcing" the worker thread to exit.  Cancelling the worker thread so it returns to the ThreadPool is the way to go.

Using a volatile bool or a ManualResetEvent will not "force" cancellation more immediately than a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: Unfortunately there are certain cases where calling built-in functions might take a very long time, and they don't have a timeout mechanism.  So the only way to stop them would be to call Thread.Abort.  For example, the Regex class... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460661/implementing-regex-timeout-in-net-4  Note however that the only time you can use Thread.Abort without security exceptions is when you're running a Silverlight 5 application in elevated trust.

Answer (score 4):

It's documented, see [Thread.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta(VS.95).aspx)

> This member has a
>   SecurityCriticalAttribute attribute,
>   which restricts it to internal use by
>   the .NET Framework for Silverlight
>   class library. Application code that
>   uses this member throws a
>   MethodAccessException.

You could use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(VS.95).aspx) (a thread safe communication method) to signal the background thread to stop.

Example code in the background thread:

```
if (!shouldStop.WaitOne(0)) 
// you could also sleep 5 seconds by using 5000, but still be stopped 
// after just 2 seconds by the other thread.
{
    // do thread stuff
}
else
{
    // do cleanup stuff and exit thread.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Silverlight code comes across the Internet, it is generally untrusted, and its execution is more restricted, as Davy pointed out.
Rather, implement a boolean exit flag in the class that is canonical for the background thread, so that you can raise this flag and use Thread.Join() instead.

Comment: boolean flag's are not recommended, those are not really threadsafe.