# timeout regex in framework 4

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing RegEx Timeout in .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460661/implementing-regex-timeout-in-net-4)

```
Regex regexpr = new Regex(anchorPattern[item.Key], RegexOptions.Singleline, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
```

"System.Text.RegulerExpression.Regex" does not contain a constructer that takes 3 arguments.
Note :The error is in the framework 4. if you use the framework 4.5 you won't encounter this error.
But i have been using framework 4 and I have to set timeout regexpr. What is the remedy to this ?

Comment: Take a look at [Implementing RegEx Timeout in .NET 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460661/implementing-regex-timeout-in-net-4) - this has an example of how to implement this yourself. (NB It doesn't let you create a `Regex` that inherantly times out, but it lets you time out individual calls to `Match` etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such constructor as the one you are using in .NET 4. Take a look at [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); the only options for constructor are:

> Regex()
>
> Regex(String)
>
> Regex(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)
>
> Regex(String, RegexOptions)

**EDIT**

You can use a [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to run the regex and `Wait` method to pass the timeout. Something like this should do the work:

```
var regexpr = new Regex(anchorPattern[item.Key], RegexOptions.Singleline);
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>regexpr.Match(foo));
var completedWithinAllotedTime = task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10));
```

Comment: ı know the regex constructer in  fw 4.0. I have asking been how to set the timeout to regex in framework 4. 0 .

Comment: @alikoyuncu, Please see the latest edit.

Comment: While the task.wait works perfectly, it leaves the regex running in the background. To end it, call task.Wait(new System.Threading.CancelationToken(true)); after the first wait. Catch the exception and put your timeout processing in there.